# How to display OpenCV mat image on PHP webpage using socket programming?

Tags: php, c++, qt, sockets, opencv

Hi I've written a c++ program using Qt which gets images from webcam and sends it to a web page through QSocket.

Mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MyTCPserver = new server(this);
    MyTCPserver->start_listen(SOCKET_PORT);

}
```

Server.cpp

```
#include "server.h"
server::server(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{
    connect( this,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this, SLOT(tcpReady()));
}
void server::ReadData(){
    QByteArray array = server_socket->read( server_socket->bytesAvailable() );
    qDebug()<<"I've read something and it is: "<<array<<"\n";

    static int counter = 0;
    cv::Mat TEST = cv::Mat(400,400,CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar::all(120));
    cv::putText(TEST,QString::number(counter++).toUtf8().constData(),cv::Point(TEST.cols*0.4,TEST.rows*0.4),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,.7,cv::Scalar(255));
    cv::imshow("TEST",TEST);
    cv::waitKey(30);
    server_socket->write((const char *)TEST.data);
}

server::~server()
{
    server_socket->disconnectFromHost();
    server_socket->waitForDisconnected();
}

void server::tcpReady()
{
    qDebug()<<"Server Is Okay \n";
    server_socket = this->nextPendingConnection();
    connect( server_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(ReadData()) );

}

bool server::start_listen(int port_no)
{

    if( !this->listen( QHostAddress::LocalHost, port_no ) )
    {
        QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error!"), tr("Cannot listen to port %1").arg(port_no) );

    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Client.php

```
<?php
    $host    = "127.0.0.1";
    $port    = 12345;
    $message = 'm ';
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");    
    socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
    $buf = '';
    $bytes = socket_recv($socket, $buf, 2048, MSG_WAITALL);
    $imgData = base64_encode($buf);
        $img = "<img src= 'data:image/png;base64, $imgData' />";
    print($img);
    socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I can send and receive strings between my c++ program and php webpage.

but when I want to send images like the above code to my php webpage Nothing is displayed in the webpage and the webpage shows a corrupted image icon.

I think my php code is wrong since it might not get what open cv is sending !!!

Any idea how to solve this ?

Edited :

as suggested in the comments I changed the server::ReadData() to the following but it is not working too !!

```
void server::ReadData(){
    QByteArray array = server_socket->read( server_socket->bytesAvailable() );
    qDebug()<<"I've read something and it is: "<<array<<"\n";

    static int counter = 0;
    cv::Mat TEST = cv::Mat(400,400,CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar::all(120));
    cv::putText(TEST,QString::number(counter++).toUtf8().constData(),cv::Point(TEST.cols*0.4,TEST.rows*0.4),CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,.7,cv::Scalar(255));
    cv::imshow("TEST",TEST);
    cv::waitKey(30);
    std::vector<uchar> BUF;
    cv::imencode(".png",TEST,BUF);
    int Size = TEST.total()*8;
    server_socket->write((const char *)BUF[0],Size);
}
```

Comment: it's already suspicious, that `server_socket->write((const char *)TEST.data);`  is not taking the image-length . now please don't tell me, that it's using strlen internally.

Comment: you're sending *pixels* only, but trying to receive a complete image. you might have to imencode() your TEST image to a png or such before sending it

Comment: but there's not such a encoding function in opencv as I'm aware of !!! unless I save it into the hard drive and then send it ... I don't want to save the image into the hard drive ... So what else ?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode

Comment: I've even wrote     int Size = TEST.total()*8;
    server_socket->write((const char *)TEST.data,Size); but the result were the same as before !

Comment: So write a complete answer and Maybe your right then you will be selected as the best answer .... thanks

Comment: yea, you got more than one problem here. also expect your packets getting fragmented, so you have to read like 2k chunks until you got it all ( you can't simply do it with 1 read call)

Comment: but my friend wrote a code using c# and it just went well with the php code !!! right now I think the problem is in the difference of image architecture of opencv and php !!!

Comment: ok. the php client will work for small images. your problems are mostly on the server side now.

Comment: so do you have any idea what to do now !!! I've added your recommendation to the above code ... but it's not working yet !

Comment: server_socket->write((const char *)(&BUF[0]),BUF.size()); // address of 1st element, and correct size

Comment: also put it on port 80 and test with a webbrowser

Comment: I tested your solution and it worked !!! but not the way you think !! when I run my c++ server program and then load the webpage, the webpage goes into loading mode and loads nothing (I waited for more than 3 minutes !!!) but when I closed the c++ program the webpage loaded the image ! what might be the problem !